# How to override a related set's "add" method in Django

Tags: django, set

I am working on a Django project and I want to send a signal when something gets added to some model's related set. E.g. we have an owner who has a set of collectables, and each time the method `owner.collectable_set.add(something)` is getting called, I want a signal like `collectable_added` or something. Signals are clear to me, but I don't know which manager(?) contains the "add" method that I want to override.

**Edit** for Xavier's request to provide more details: you can easily override a model’s `save` method, by simply defining it and calling the "super-`save`" so it gets properly saved with some extra functionality. But I wonder where to override a related set's `add` method.

Gosh, I think I haven't brought in any further details, but I think it should be clear what I want to do even from the first paragraph.

**Edit 2:** [This](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) is the method I want to override. Is it recommended to do so, or do you suggest another way to place the sending of the signal?

Comment: Your question is really vague. If you can provide a pseudo-code, or try to explain it better, I think more people could help.

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution I found, the [`m2m_changed` signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed). Took me quite some searching and reading. Furthermore, I found out that it is not trivial to extend the `ManyRelatedManager` class, which would have been the other option. But with the `m2m_changed` signal I can rely on built-in functions which is the preferred way most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [RelatedManager Class](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L407).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It looks like the solution, but i forgot to mention that i am dealing with a m2m-relation. So in this case the ManyRelatedManager class would be the one to extend or to insert the signal into. BUT it is not trivial to extend this class since it is dynamically generated. Thanks anyway. I'll post a solution i found but haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching (thanks to this Paul's hint), I came across this [snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2552/) that helped to explain the m2m_changed implementation to **intercept** not override the add method on the ManyRelatedManager. It appears that the manager on a many-to-many relationship happens on the fly, so it's not trivial to override the method.