# How to do validation on django's ManyRelatedManager?

Tags: python, django, django-related-manager

I would like to change the behavior, maybe overwriting, when I add an instance to a M2M relation, so that I could do something like this:

```
try:
    my_instance.one_field_set.add( another_instance )
except ValidationError:
    # do something
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes but don't do it that way.

1) Use can use an explicit [`intermediate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) model for your M2M relationship and
provide it with a custom [`manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager) in which you can replace the `create` method.

2) In my opinion though, the best way is to have on one of these models an
instance method `add_something` which provides the necessary validation and exception-handling
logic.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question, that is not exactly what I wanted, but helps as a workaround.

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=MyModel.my_field.through)
def check(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['action'] == 'pre_add':
        add = AnotherModel.objects.filter(pk__in=kwargs["pk_set"]) # instances being added
        # your validation here...
```

Thanks to [mamachanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213000/mamachanko) on his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881368/django-how-to-override-a-related-sets-add-method).

Comment: This makes sense only if you want to hook it against django models you don't control(e.g. django built-in models). Or you want to subscribe many actions on this specific event. Not for what you asked.