# Django Many2Many constraint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am using Django with Django-Rest-Framework (no forms, no django_admin). I have the following models

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...


class Sector(models.Model):
    ...
    company_id = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee)


class Employee(models.Model):
    ...
    company_id = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

**Employee** can be in multiple **Sectors** and a **Sector** can have multiple **Employees**. (ManyToMany).

I want to add a constraint **employee.company_id** == **sector.company_id** in order to add a record into the Many2Many table.

I can do this validation in the serializers from the DRF, but I also want to handle this on the model level.

I added a *through* table in the ManyToManyField

```
class Sector(models.Model):
    ...
    company_id = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, through='M2MTable')


class M2MTable:
    ...

    def save():
        # employee.company_id and sector.company_id validation is done here
```

This will handle saving an M2MTable object, but however this will not handle related object references **Sector.employees.add(Employee)**

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881368/how-to-override-a-related-sets-add-method-in-django) I found out I can achieve this with m2m signals.

Is there another way of handling this